# Where does the expression "checkmate" come from?

Tags: checkmate, history, terminology

While watching *The Queen's Gambit* my partner asked me: why do they say "checkmate"? But she wanted to know what is the origin of this expression, not its meaning. And I realized I didn't actually know. So, what is the origin of the expression "checkmate" and its etymology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/checkmate), *checkmate* comes from the Middle English *chekmaten*, which is derived from the Anglo-French *eschec mat*. And this came from the Persian *shāh māt* through the Arabic language.

The Persian word *shāh* means king. (With a definite article, it becomes *as-shāh*, the king.)

But I found two different interpretations for *māt*:

- unable to escape ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/checkmate))
- dead ([Dictionary of the Spanish Royal Academy](https://dle.rae.es/mate?m=form), [Treasure of the French Language](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?75;s=2924604180;r=2;nat=;sol=0;))

So, *as-shāh māt* -> checkmate = the king is dead!

Comment: Also the word “מת” in Hebrew means death. It could be a source... Transliterated, it is “meit”. (Sorry I cannot do the phonetic thing lol)